# Finding Variance of random vector $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance

> A random vector $(X,Y)$ has a continuous distribution with a density function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}c⋅x & \text{when }0 ≤ x ≤ 2, \max\{0,1−x\} ≤ y ≤2−x\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ where $c > 0$ is a constant. Find variance of a $Y$ conditioned on $X = 1.5$, $Var(Y |X = 1.5)$.

Here is my attempt

> [image]

I found $c = \frac 67$ with the given integral. Is it correct ? Also, I want to ask how can I find variance?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show us your computations.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded my computations as image

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: need to get $E(X^2),E(Y^2),E(XY),E(X),E(Y)$ to get variance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c=6/7$ is correct.

Similarly, :

$$\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) = \frac 67\left(\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{2-x} xg(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx + \int_1^2 \int_{0}^{2-x} x g(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\right)$$

And for the conditional variance

$$\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X=1.5)=\dfrac {\mathsf E(Y^2\,\mathbf 1_{X=1.5})}{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X=1.5})} -\left(\dfrac{\mathsf E(Y\,\mathbf 1_{X=1.5})}{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X=1.5})}\right)^2$$

Where: $$\mathsf E(Y^j\,\mathbf 1_{X=k}) = \frac 67\left(\mathbf 1_{k\in[0,1)}~k\int_{1-k}^{2-k} y^j\,\mathrm dy + \mathbf 1_{k\in[1,2]}~k \int_{0}^{2-k} y^j\,\mathrm dy\right)$$

Comment: $$\mathsf E(Y^j\,\mathbf 1_{X=k}) = \frac 67\left(\mathbf 1_{k\in[0,1)}~k\int_{1-k}^{2-k} y^j\,\mathrm dy + \mathbf 1_{k\in[1,2]}~k \int_{0}^{2-k} y^j\,\mathrm dy\right)$$ What does  $1_{k\in[1,2]}$ mean in this formula ?

Comment: @user1074987 It is an **indicator function**, which is equal to $1$ when the condition is met, otherwise equal to $0$.  $$\mathbf 1_{k\in[1,2]}=\begin{cases}1 &:& 1\leq k\leq 2\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$